# Integrating on the form $\sqrt { k+f\left( x \right) } $

Tags: integration

I'm having some problems integrating $$\int _{ 0 }^{ 4 } \sqrt { 1+\left( \frac { 1 }{ 2\sqrt { x }  }  \right) ^{ 2 } } dx$$
I've gotten to $$\int_0^4 \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4x}} dx$$
Which isn't a whole lot..

Comment: $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4x}}=t$ works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT Try substitution $\sqrt x = t$, you'll get $\int_0^2 \sqrt{1+4t^2} dt$

Comment: @Viktor Notice you still need some trigonometric substitution.

Comment: @SimpleArt Yes, a trigonometric substitution would finish the work

Comment: Oh, I solved it using a different method. There was actually a $$\sqrt{x}$$ I could multiply in.